# .NET WebApi jsonapi.org support

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api

Does anyone know if there is a media formatter out there to support the jsonapi.org spec (application/vnd.api+json).

If not has anyone started (or looking at starting) a project to implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>For the record, as of today the answer seems to be no.</strike> Best I could find was this guy: http://www.emadibrahim.com/2014/04/09/emberjs-and-asp-net-web-api-and-json-serialization/ and that only tackles a tiny part of the problem.

I've been trying this for a while…unfortunately I tried to make something that was really smart and would automagically handle a data model from Entity Framework with almost no work. I was getting close to thinking about releasing it...and then I found out they changed a bunch of stuff in EF 6 (all models are supposed to be POCOs and the context is now a DbContext instead of an ObjectContext) and I'm probably going to have to essentially start over…which is why I started looking again to see if someone else was doing it and found your question.

Let me know if you're still looking for this, and I'll keep you updated.

## UPDATE

I've just published a codeplex project that aims to provide exactly what I've described above. It's called [JSONAPI.NET](https://jsonapi.codeplex.com) and while it's very early, it already does quite a bit. Documentation is sparse, and I don't have NuGet packages yet…but take a look everyone and see if it's useful for you. Feedback is encouraged! You can contact me from the project page in the link.

Comment: I'm doing exact same research now as we're leaning towards releasing our API in that format. It's quite likely we'll develop our own and if we do, we'll almost surely open it.

Comment: @JacekGorgoń I talked to my boss and got permission to release what I've been working on. I'm planning on putting it up on codeplex. I'm on vacation next week, but will try and clean up what I have and post it there before the end of October. I will post more info here when I do!

Comment: @JacekGorgoń and Stuart : Unsure if you'll be notified of my updated answer, if not, I've posted my own solution in a CodePlex project, now linked in the answer.

Comment: I started working on our own solution in the meantime. I reviewed your solution and liked it, but it probably needs more work and we'll need a production ready solution quite soon, so we'll give it a try ourselves. We'll probably share it once it's done. Anyway, thanks for sharing.

Comment: Great answer, and better yet is the project itself, but it seems it was abandoned. =(

Comment: @TheFabricio I'm guessing you're the one who came by and asked this in an issue on GitHub. Not quite, and I'm planning to get back to it myself too--my work duties changed, but may be getting better soon.

Comment: @S'pht'Kr - Sorry I have only just seen this update! What you have put together looks good. I'm also finally marking this as an answer.